# Редактирование Односвязного списка C++

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Ранее делал через Классы, но сейчас стоит задача с помощью структур. Совсем не получается реализовать 2 функции.

1. Разработать функцию, которая удаляет из списка  все узлы в четных позициях.
2. Разработать функцию, которая вставляет в список L2 после каждой пары узлов новый узел со значением равным сумме значений двух предыдущих узлов.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> using namespace std;
>
> struct list
> {
>     int value = 0;
>     list* next = NULL;
>     void deleteNextElement()
>     {
>         if (next != NULL)
>         {
>             list* temp = next;
>             next = temp->next;
>             delete temp;
>         }
>     }
> };
>
> list* addnode(list* root, int newvalue)
> {
>     if (root != NULL)
>     {
>         list* newnode = new list;
>         newnode->value = newvalue;
>
>         list* i = root;
>         while (i->next != NULL)
>         {
>             i = i->next; 
>         }
>         i->next = newnode;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         root = new list;
>         root->value = newvalue;
>     }
>     return root;
>
> }
> struct list* deletelem(list* root2)
> {
>     list* q, * s;
>     s = root2;
>     if (s != NULL)
>     {
>         while (s != NULL) {
>             if (s->next->value < 0) {
>                 q = s;s = s->next;
>                 delete q;
>             }
>             else {
>                 s = s->next;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return root2;
> }
> int getSize(list* root)
> {
>     int size = 1;
>     list* i = root;
>     while (i->next != NULL)
>     {
>         size++;
>         i = i->next;
>     }
>     //cout << size<<endl;
>     return size;
> }
> void printlist(list* root)
> {
>     if (root != NULL)
>     {
>         list* i = root;
>         cout << i->value << " ";
>         while (i->next != NULL)
>         {
>             i = i->next;
>             cout << i->value << " ";
>         }
>         cout << endl;
>     }
>     else cout << "Список пуст!";
> }
>
> list* addeq(list* root1, list* root2, list* root3)
> {
>     if (root1 != NULL)
>     {
>         list* i = root1;
>         while (i->next != NULL)
>         {
>             root3 = addnode(root3, i->value);
>
>             i = i->next;
>             if (i->next == NULL)
>                 root3 = addnode(root3, i->value);
>         }
>     }
>     if (root2 != NULL)
>     {
>         
>             list* j = root2;
>             while (j->next != NULL)
>             {
>                 root3 = addnode(root3, j->value);
>                 j = j->next;
>                 if(j->next == NULL)
>                     root3 = addnode(root3, j->value);
>             }
>     }
>     return root3;
> }
> void insert(list* root) // РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ ВСТАВКУ ПОСЛЕ 2УХ
> {
>
> }
> void delChet(list* root) // УДАЛЕНИЕ В ЧЕТНЫХ УЗЛАХ
> {
>
> }
> list* unique(list* lst) 
> {
>     list* t, * q, * p = lst, * i = lst;
>     while (p != NULL) 
>     {
>         for (t = i = p->next; i != NULL; ) 
>         {
>             if (i->value == p->value) 
>             {
>                 q = i->next;
>                 if (t == i)
>                     t = p->next = i->next;
>                 else
>                     t->next = i->next;
>
>                 delete i;
>                 i = q;
>                 continue;
>             }
>             t = i;
>             i = i->next;
>         }
>         p = p->next;
>     }
>     return lst;
> ```

Comment: в **deletelem** условие `s->next->value < 0` поменяйте на `index % 2 == 1` - будет удалять чётные.

Comment: @AlexGlebe не подскажешь тогда как определять индекс  у однонаправленного списка?